# tengo problemas para iniciar mi aplicacion en react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio

cuando intento iniciar mi archivo en react me sale esto cuando pongo en la terminal el
npx

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

intenta con:

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

y después ejecuta el comando de `create-react-app` normalmente